# export BLOB from nexus enterprise manager

Tags: nexusdb

I'm trying to convert a bunch of blob files back into PDFs.

Currently they look like this:

[image: Nexus Enterprise Manager]

I haven't really found much on the internet, and the few guides or post i've found, haven't yielded any results.

Has anyone ever tried doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any existing bulk export utility, however you should be able to use the Enterprise Manager tool in your image to save each individual BLOB as PDF. A bulk export utility could be created on request.